# How do I select distinct data in a table based on a max value of one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
A        B         C        D         E        F 
James    Michael   123      Hello     World    1
James    Michael   123      Hello     World    5
James    Michael   123      Hello     World    7
Harold   Reynolds  345      There     Poop     1
John     Lowland   555      Woh       Pop      1
Howard   Yow       255      Man       That     1
```

I want to be able to select ALL the rows based on the MAX value of F.

Result should be:

```
James    Michael   123      Hello     World 
Harold   Reynolds  345      There     Poop     
John     Lowland   555      Woh       Pop      
Howard   Yow       255      Man       That
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "C" ORDER BY "F" DESC) AS RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a5878/3/0)

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function generates a number for every row starting from 1 for each group of fields utilized in the `PARTITION BY` clause (optional) and the order is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause (required).

Note: I'm assuming your `C` field is sufficient for identifying a row, but you may need to add fields to the `PARTITION BY` clause if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

We can use row_number and partition the result and get only 1 row from the partition

```
   Select * from 
   ( select *, row_number() over (    partition by A, B, C,D ,E order by F desc ) as seq from tableA) T
   Where T.seq =1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is pg `DISTINCT ON` is the correct way:

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON ("A","B","C","D","E") "A","B","C","D","E","F"
FROM table1
ORDER BY "A","B","C","D","E","F" DESC) AS q
ORDER BY "F" DESC;
```

The outer query is there just to put James on top.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a5878/12)